# Localization ground rules

Tags: localization

I've just submitted my first localized app to the iPhone app store the other day. I decided to do it to learn about application localization, and because my app was simple enough to stumble through localizing with my mediocre french. I know I didn't do everything "right", but I learned a lot from doing it once. I'd like to keep doing this for all my future apps.

For one thing, I learned to code with localization in mind, but don't start localizing until your app is ready to be released. I spent way too much time doing small tweaks in 2 UI files.

What are your favourite localization basics, cardinal rules, and best practices?
I'm thinking mostly for small hobby developers like myself, although stuff from the big leagues would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest one for me is **don't concatenate strings**:

Bad:

```
"You have " + messageCount + " messages";
```

Good:

```
"You have {0} messages"
```

Word order varies from language to language, and so you can't assume where in a sentence your dynamic data might occur.

Comment: wow, apparently localization is an unpopular tag. only 12 views, and one response. weird. anyway, thanks mike! you get a checkmark!

Comment: Yes, it's a lonely discipline:) Good luck with your app sales.

Answer (score 3):

In your UI, allow for about 30-50% expansion of translations from English.  A method I learned early in my career was to produce a 'pig latin' localized version of the UI.

If your user interface is still legible in Pig Latin, it will probably be legible in real languages.

> Ifway ouryay userway interfaceway isway illstay egiblelay inway  Igpay
>   Atinlay, itway illway obablypray ebay egiblelay inway  ealray
>   anguageslay.

Comment: Ha! This is probably the most humorous, as well as useful, reply I've seen on SO. nice.

Answer (score 1):

- Use Unicode for all strings - UTF-16 or UTF-8. If reading/writing to any program/format that doesn't assume that by default, make sure you specify UTF-16 or UTF-8 explicitly.
- As Mike Sickler said, don't concatenate strings. Better yet, don't have sentences with inserts, since you don't know how the insert affects the rest of the sentence - different languages have different rules regarding plural / etc.

Bad: `"You have " + messageCount + " messages"`

Better: `"You have {0} messages"`  (but what if {0} == 1? Do you write message(s)? What about Hebrew, where "one" comes after the noun, but other numbers before?)

Best: `"Messages: {0}"`

- As rhsatrhs said, allow 30-50% expansion. In my (big league) company, we usually assume that German is the longest, although I found out that sometimes Russian got over 100% larger. I suspect it's sometimes translators who don't know the exact term, so they write a longer description using close term (Example: Symbol ==> source code reference marker).